# JavaScript - replace and create vars

Tags: javascript, string, variables, replace

I have an POST AJAX command that returns the following:

```
`email{admin@stackoverflow.com} cid{215}`
```

What I want do is replace the email{} and the cid{} with using only the values as vars

```
var email = 'admin@stackoverflow.com'
var customer_id = 215;
```

They would appear like that. Is there a cleaner way than:

```
var result = "email{admin@stackoverflow.com} cid{215}"; 

// change to        admin@stackoverflow.com cid{215}
var replace1 = result.replace("email{");
var replace1a = replace1.replace("}");

// change to        admin@stackoverflow.com 215
var replace2 = result.replace("cid{");
var replace2a = replace1.replace("}");

// now we have an email, with a space and a number
// admin@stackoverflow.com 215 make before space string
// this would be email

// now make only the int a string called cid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use a regular expression to extract desired data:

```
var response = "email{admin@stackoverflow.com} cid{215}";
var regex = /email\{(.*)\} cid\{(.*)\}/;
var data = response.match(regex);
```

Now you can easily obtain values you want:

```
var email = data[1];
var customer_id = +data[2];
```

Comment: Where can I learn more about regex. Could you explain more. I take .* gets the string value like .htaccess and nginx url rewrites?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: start by reading comprehensive [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: How would I detect spaces. Example Fullname{John Smith Andrew} or Fullname{John Smith}, I am using `var regex = /email\{(.*)\} cid\{(.*)\} fullname\{(.*)\}/;` but I get the NaN